Crash with no specific location (Android studio)
My app shows error in Google play analytics that I can't replicate mainly because it does not show me it's location.
I can only assume that it is related to some onClick method from one of many XML Files which is missing a name of the method.
Usually errors related to onClick method shows which XML or java file it occurred it, but not in this case and it drives me crazy.
Anyone had this kid of experience and how did you manage to locate the error?
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod (AppCompatViewInflater.java:505)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick (AppCompatViewInflater.java:463)
  at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:7670)
  at android.view.View.performClickInternal (View.java:7636)
  at android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal (Unknown Source)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:30599)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:958)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:205)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:294)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8376)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:640)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:982)```


